# Finding the critical points of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Find the critical points of $f(x,y) = \sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(x+y)$ with the open domain $D=$ {$0\lt x \lt \pi, 0 \lt y \lt \pi$}

**Answer:**

I have found that there is a critical point $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ however I can't seem to understand how there can be any more in this particular domain.

Comment: Unless I've made a calculation error, I don't think there's a critical point at $(\pi/2, \pi/2)$.  The gradient doesn't vanish there.

Comment: The partial derivative should be $0$ for multiple variables

Comment: I dont think sin,cos is undefined anywhere  so there are no undefined derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If we consider $$F = \sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(x+y)$$ we have $$F'_x=\sin (x) \sin (y) \cos (x+y)+\cos (x) \sin (y) \sin (x+y)=\sin (y) \sin (2 x+y)$$ $$F'_y=\sin (x) \sin (y) \cos (x+y)+\sin (x) \cos (y) \sin (x+y)=\sin (x) \sin (x+2 y)$$ I am sure that you can take it from here and find all critical points.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I did manage to reach this point (albeit in a very long way because I decided to expand $\sin(x+y$ instantly however when making both of these equal to zero, I can't see how to calculate the critical points

Comment: I have tried this again and I've managed to get a critical point of $(\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{-\pi}{3})$

Comment: If you exclude $x=0$ and $y=0$, you have to consider $2x+y=k\pi$ and $x+2y=k\pi$

Comment: That is what I did and I got a critical point outside of the bounds of the domain

Comment: What about $x=y=\frac \pi 3$ and $x=y=\frac{2\pi} 3$ ?

Comment: I agree with the first critical point however when $x= \frac{2\pi}{3}$  then $y = \frac{-\pi}{3}$

Comment: When I write $k\pi$, $k\neq 0$